# Node.js chai is a item object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, chai

Im using ECMAScript 6 classes I have a class called Item and I want to test if a function returns a item object over just an object is their a way to do this?

Currently i just have `expect(itemObject).is.a('object');` but just `{}` fulfills that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`instanceof` assertion](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_instanceof):

```
expect(itemObject).to.be.instanceof(Item);
```

Comment: You deserve a +1 simply for understanding the question - good work!